# Enabling and Disabling Radio buttons on button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons namely

```
Popular

Others
```

Two buttons

```
Edit 

Cancel
```

Initially radio buttons would be disabled when i click on edit button radio buttons should be enabled and when i click on cancel button again it should be disabled..

currently im only able to enable when i click on edit button but i'm failed to disable it when i click on cancel button can somebody help me out in achieving it Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/UhEut/452/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label>
        <input id='r_popular' class='pop_others' type='radio' name='section_pop_others' disabled checked />Popular
    </label>
    <label>
        <input id='r_others' class='pop_others' type='radio' name='section_pop_others' disabled />Others
    </label>
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).click('.edit',function()
{
    $('input[name=section_pop_others]').attr("disabled",true);
});

$(document).click('.cancel',function()
{
    $('input[name=section_pop_others]').attr("disabled",false);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is your code not working?

```
$(document).click('whatever here',function(){
// This block is run for every click event occuring anywhere on the document 
}
```

Than what is the right way to do this:

```
 $('Your selector').click(function(){
   // This block will run when click event occurs on Your selector
})
```

Change your code:

```
$(document).click('.cancel',function()
$(document).click('.edit',function()
```

To this:

```
    $('.cancel').click(function(){
    $('.edit').click(function()
```

[** js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UhEut/454/)

[Go to this link to learn more about .click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

```
            $('.edit').click(function()
            {
            $('input[name=section_pop_others]').removeAttr("disabled");
            });

            $('.cancel').click(function()
            {
            $('input[name=section_pop_others]').attr("disabled","disabled");
            });
```

Modified your code

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the click event to the document instead of the elements based off selectors.

The two options for click:

1. .click(handler function)
2. .click(eventdata,handler function)

You are passing the selector to the event data.

Attach the click events to the objects you are targeting by using the selector.

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    $('input[name=section_pop_others]').attr("disabled", false);
});

$('.cancel').click(function () {
    $('input[name=section_pop_others]').attr("disabled", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned you are using the `click` even wrong, but you also need to attach your event handlers to `$(document).ready` for them to work.

This works:

HTML:

```
<div>    
    <input id="r_popular" class="pop_others" type="radio" name="section_pop_others" checked="checked" />Popular
    <input id="r_popular" class="pop_others" type="radio" name="section_pop_others" />Others    
</div>   
<button class="edit">Edit</button>
<button class="cancel">cancel</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pop_others').attr('disabled',true);

    $('.cancel').click(function() { 
        $('.pop_others').attr('disabled',true);    
    });

    $('.edit').click(function() { 
        $('.pop_others').attr('disabled',false);    
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.edit').on('click',function()
{
    $('input[name=section_pop_others]').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('.cancel').on('click',function()
{   
    $('input[name=section_pop_others]').prop("disabled",true);
});

Write click for button instead of writing to document it will trigger both the event same time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
    $('.cancel').on ('click', function () {
        $('input[name=section_pop_others]').attr("disabled",true);
    });
    $('.edit').on ('click', function () {
       ('input[name=section_pop_others]').attr("disabled",false);
    });
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UhEut/460/)